# issue mounting LV to /tmp in RHEL

Tags: linux, mount, lvm, fstab

I tried mounting an LV to the /tmp directory and it has seemed to mess up my RHEL VM.  To mount, I did the following:

```
1. Added following line to fstab:
    /dev/VolGroup00/lvol0   /tmp         ext3   defaults    0 0
2. restarted RHEL - 'shutdown -r now'
```

lvol0 is of type ext3 and should be working fine.  I have tried mounting it simply by saying `mount /dev/VolGroup00/lvol0 /tmp`, but this does not exactly work either.

The issue is that my display gets messed up.  I can no longer remote desktop into the machine using nomachine.  I can, however, still ssh into the VM.  When I ssh with x11 on, I cannot open any GUI programs.  This is what gedit says:

```
The application 'gedit' lost its connection to the display localhost:11.0;
most likely the X server was shut down or you killed/destroyed
the application.
```

I tried to restart the x server with `startx -- :1`, but it just spits out a bunch of errors about trying to get the display and then hangs.

Also, I have tried to unmount the tmp directory with `umount /tmp` and it says I am unable to do it because the /tmp directory is is use.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that your new `/tmp` is writable by anyone and has the sticky bit set?

Comment: @SamiLaine I do not have the sticky bit set, but it is writable.  Is that needed to be able to use the display?

Comment: apparently it is.  I tried mounting the /tmp drive explicitly, then running gedit and got the display issue.  I then added the sticky bit and still got the display issue so I thought it wasnt a sticky bit issue.  I ended up restarting the machine with the sticky bit set and that fixed it!  Thanks for the help!